# How do I unlock fast travel?

Tags: just-cause-3

I saw a stream where the player was able to right click and select fast travel. How can I enable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to unlock the ability to fast travel by progressing through the main story. You can tell if it is part of the main story by the orange bull head icon on the map.

Once you reach the mission *Friends Like These* you will be able to fast travel to shrines, settlements and challenges on the map. Using fast travel requires 1 flare each time. You can unlock infinite fast travels for a certain area by discovering all the shrines in it.

Comment: Thanks. Cleared the story mission which unlocked fast travel